# A question about "this" reserved word in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, this

I've a question about `this` reserved word in JavaScript.

Check out codes below:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    if (!this.prototype[name]) {
        this.prototype[name] = func;
    }        
};

String.method('deentityify', function () {

    var entity = {
        quot: '"',
        lt: '<',
        gt: '>'
    };

    return function () {

        /*if (this === String.prototype) {
            alert('true');
        } else {
            alert('false');
        }*/

        return this.replace(/&([^&;]+);/g,
            function (a, b) {
                var r = entity[b];
                return typeof r === 'string' ? r : a;
            }
        );
    };
}());

document.write('&lt;&quot;&gt;'.deentityify());
```

You can edit codes above at: http://jsfiddle.net/G3Tkm/

My question is:

What is the `this` reserved word at line 27 `return this.replace(/&([^&;]+);/g,` is?

I guess: `this === String.prototype`, but it isn't.

The type of `'&lt;&quot;&gt;'` is string, and type of `this` is object. So `this !== '&lt;&quot;&gt;'`

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever I find a `this` keyword in JavaScript code I usually just look upwards, until I find the surrounding function it's in.

Then I try and understand how this function gets called from the *outside*. This is important because the value of `this` changes based on how the function is being called.

From your code it seems that `String.method()`'s job is to add methods to the prototype chain of the *String* object. This is something that you shouldn't really do, it's sort of bad JavaScript behavior and might cause some issues later on.

However, for the sake of an explanation, whenever you call the `deentityify` method on a string, such as `"foo".deentityify()` - suppose this calls whatever you assigned in `String.method('deentityify', function () {` - `this` becomes in effect another function itself (if `String.method` works as I think).

So, when using `"foo".deentityify()()` your `this` will refer to the caller, which is `"foo".deentityify()`.  And the caller of `"foo".deentityify()` is in fact `"foo"` itself.

So basically `this`, in your case, refers to the String object you're calling the method from.